# Elasticsearch: Is it possible to sort collapsed results by a nested field?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a fairly complex mapping which is storing products, and within each document it contains a nested array of pre-calculated prices for each customer.

There may be multiple versions of each product in the index (with unique codes). Alternative products are grouped by a common `xrefs_hash`. The query I'm writing needs to select the best product for each customer (i.e. aggregate/collapse on the `xrefs_hash`), and then select the top product based on the value of the `prices.weight` nested field.

The `prices.weight` field is a float which we've pre-calculated based on the shops' customer settings on how they want to prioritise their own items. A hash is created from these settings (stored in `prices.pricing_hash`) so that we can store a single set of pricing if multiple customers share the same settings.

The index contains up to 300,000 products and can end up with ~100,000,000 documents once all prices are calculated and inserted.

The mapping looks something like this (shortened for brevity):

```php
'mappings' => [
    '_source' => [
        'enabled' => true,
    ],
    'dynamic' => false,
    'properties' => [
        'dealer_item_id' => [
            'type' => 'integer',
        ],
        'code' => [
            'type' => 'text',
            'analyzer' => 'custom_code_analyzer',
            'fields' => [
                'raw' => [
                    'type' => 'keyword',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'xrefs' => [
            'type' => 'text',
            'analyzer' => 'custom_code_analyzer',
            'fields' => [
                'raw' => [
                    'type' => 'keyword',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'xrefs_hash' => [
            'type' => 'keyword',
        ],
        'title' => [
            'type' => 'text',
            'analyzer' => 'custom_english_analyzer',
            'fields' => [
                'ngram_title' => [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'analyzer' => 'custom_title_analyzer',
                ],
                'raw' => [
                    'type' => 'keyword',
                ],
            ],
        ],

        ...

        'prices' => [
            'type' => 'nested',
            'dynamic' => false,
            'properties' => [
                'pricing_hash' => [
                    'type' => 'keyword',
                    'index' => true,
                ],
                'unit_price' => [
                    'type' => 'float',
                    'index' => true,
                ],
                'pricebreaks' => [
                    'type' => 'object',
                    'dynamic' => false,
                    'properties' => [
                        'quantity' => [
                            'type' => 'integer',
                            'index' => false,
                        ],
                        'price' => [
                            'type' => 'integer',
                            'index' => false,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'weight' => [
                    'type' => 'float',
                    'index' => true,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Example documents:

```js
{
    "dealer_item_id": 122023,
    "code": "ABC123A",
    "xrefs": [
        "ABC123A",
        "ABC123B",
    ],
    "title": "Product A",
    "xrefs_hash": "16d5415674c8365f63329b11ffc88da109590cec",
    "prices": [
        {
            "pricebreaks": [
                {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "price": 9.75,
                    "contract": false
                }
            ],
            "weight": 0.20512820512820512,
            "pricing_hash": "aabe06b7",
            "unit_price": 9.75,
        },
        {
            "pricebreaks": [
                {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "price": 9.75,
                    "contract": false
                }
            ],
            "weight": 0.20512820512820512,
            "pricing_hash": "73643f3b",
            "unit_price": 9.75,
        }
    ]
},
{
    "dealer_item_id": 124293,
    "code": "ABC1234B",
    "xrefs": [
        "ABC123A",
        "ABC123B",
    ],
    "title": "Product B",
    "xrefs_hash": "16d5415674c8365f63329b11ffc88da109590cec",
    "prices": [
        {
            "contract_item": false,
            "pricebreaks": [
                {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "price": 7.39,
                    "contract": false
                }
            ],
            "weight": 0.33829499323410017,
            "pricing_hash": "aabe06b7",
            "unit_price": 7.39,
        },
        {
            "pricebreaks": [
                {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "price": 9.75,
                    "contract": false
                }
            ],
            "weight": 0.20512820512820512,
            "pricing_hash": "73643f3b",
            "unit_price": 9.75,
        }
    ]
},
```

Example query:

```js
{
    "track_total_hits": 100000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "nested": {
                                "path": "prices",
                                "score_mode": "none",
                                "inner_hits": {
                                    "_source": {
                                        "include": [
                                            "prices"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "query": {
                                    "bool": {
                                        "must": [
                                            {
                                                "term": {
                                                    "prices.pricing_hash": "aabe06b7"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "code.raw": "RX58022"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "must_not": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "disabled": true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "_source": {
        "includes": [
            "code",
            "dealer_item_id",
            "title",
            "xrefs"
        ]
    },
    "collapse": {
        "field": "xrefs_hash",
        "inner_hits": {
            "name": "best_xrefs",
            "sort": {
                "prices.weight": "desc"
            },
            "size": 1
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "xrefs_count": {
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "xrefs_hash",
                "precision_threshold": 40000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using a collapse query to select the best product, but this does not seem to support sorting by the nested `prices.weight` field.

I've also tried aggretating based on the `xrefs_hash`, but this seems to make pagination at the category level impossible.

The above example query almost works, but does not return the collapsed results in the correct order. When inspecting the query it seems to be replacing the collapse sort with `Infinity`, which apparently ES does if a document does not contain a sort field.

### So what I'm wondering is; is it possible to:

1. Return 1 document per unique `xref_hash` value
2. Return the specific document whith the highest `prices.weight` value, matching customer's `pricing_hash`
3. Also make this work with pagination

Comment: have you tried using [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) inside of your `xrefs_hash` terms agg?

Comment: @mikeb Yes but I can't seem to hit on the right combination of aggregations. We can't sort the top_hits results by the nested field. I'm thinking perhaps this needs a `reverse_nested` aggregation to work?